# Send a post request with an Electron webview

Tags: javascript, webview, http-post, electron

I want to send a `POST` request with an [Electron webview](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md) from the outer script. At the moment I just set the `src` attribute to trigger a page load, which sends a `GET` request:

```
<webview id="view">
<script>
document.getElementById('view').setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/?foo=bar');
</script>
```

Is there any way to navigate the webview to a URL by sending a `POST` request? Maybe a method of the `webview`, instead of just hacking with the `src`?

Comment: Maybe load a special page that executes `<form method="post">`? Could that work? Or inject that JavaScript code into the `<webview>` that does that?

Comment: I think you have the best answer that will work in all cases - injecting a FORM into the webview that you can submit by programatically pressing the submit button etc. ! If you submit it as an answer you'll win the bounty (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now there is a new [`<webview>.loadURL()`](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/#webviewloadurlurl-options) method with a `postData` option in the docs. I haven't used it yet but it looks exactly like what I was looking for in the past.

It seems they added it as a feature in the meantime.

Answer (score 6):

You can execute arbitrary code from within the webview context with [`.executeJavaScript`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md#webviewexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback).

Moreover your code has access to all browser built-in apis. Easiest would be to use [`fetch`](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch), with method set to `post`.

In your case (provided the webview has been already loaded; for example its `.src` has been set):

```
document.getElementById('view')
  .executeJavaScript('fetch("http://example.com/?foo=bar", {method: "post"});');
```

Some remarks:

1. The origin of the request is controlled by `.src` of the webview.
2. It seems that all default security policy are still used by webview - specifically you cannot make calls to `http:` from `https:`.
3. It is bit painful to pass code as a string.

Comment: My intention was to navigate the webview to that POST call URL, this would just call the URL in the background, right?

Comment: It wouldn't just "call" the website. It will get the complete webpage HTML etc. That page won't be displyaed in the webview but you could replace the webview's `innerText` with that returned by the `fetch POST`. This may or may not work. You could also parse the HTML returned. It depends what you want to do. But you cannot directly navigate a webview using POST at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Webview element does not have a property like "method" of Form so you can not specify a particular HTTP method for its request. I recommend you to use AngularJS or any other JS frameworks to archive your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I found two workaround since `<webview>` does not seem to currently have any way to send a `POST` request.

1. Maybe the site you're using will let you send the form as a `GET` by adding any form elements to the URL's query string. It turns out the site I was using did allow this and I wouldn't've guessed had I not actually tried.
2. You might be able to send a `POST` manually through AJAX/fetch etc then replace the HTML of the page in the webview with the HTML returned by your manual `POST`. You can achieve this using `.executeJavaScript()` and/or Electron's IPC.

Neither workaround will work in every case. It might be worth filing a feature request with the Electron team too...

So I just went ahead and submitted a feature request. You can follow it here: https://discuss.atom.io/t/add-http-post-method-to-webview/29702